# nginx website on Ubuntu 18 not loading on public IP

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to host a website via nginx on Amazon AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18.04. I started by following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04). I ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install nginx`. Then, I ran `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'`. Running `sudo ufw status` returned the following;

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

After that I ran `systemctl status nginx` which returned:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-03-21 14:30:31 UTC; 1min 17s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 2657 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code
  Process: 2644 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process
 Main PID: 2661 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2661 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_pro
           └─2663 nginx: worker process

Mar 21 14:30:31 ip-172-31-29-16 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web serv
Mar 21 14:30:31 ip-172-31-29-16 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID f
Mar 21 14:30:31 ip-172-31-29-16 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web serve
lines 1-15/15 (END)...skipping...
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-03-21 14:30:31 UTC; 1min 17s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 2657 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2644 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2661 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2661 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─2663 nginx: worker process

Mar 21 14:30:31 ip-172-31-29-16 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Mar 21 14:30:31 ip-172-31-29-16 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Mar 21 14:30:31 ip-172-31-29-16 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I then tried to fix the `Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument` error. I did that by doing `mkdir /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d`, then `printf "[Service]\nExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1\n"` which returned

> [Service]
>   ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1

After that I ran `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf` and inserted the above quote into there and saved it. Then `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart nginx`. After that running `systemctl status nginx` returned this:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-03-21 14:54:44 UTC; 16s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 2941 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2957 ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2955 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2944 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2956 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2956 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─2962 nginx: worker process

Mar 21 14:54:44 ip-172-31-29-16 systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Mar 21 14:54:44 ip-172-31-29-16 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Mar 21 14:54:44 ip-172-31-29-16 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I figured everything should be working now, so I ran `curl localhost` and that returned

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe I should also be able to access this from my home PC, so I did `curl ifconfig.me` to get my public IP and then I went to http://PUBLICIP, but it said This site can’t be reached.

Can someone help me fix this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was my AWS security groups, I added an inbound rule to accept all TCP and now it works.