# Cannot reach nginx on ubuntu AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to launch a Python webapp, doing the same as I usually do (not that I totally know what I'm doing). Usually I see a "Bad Gateway" when I'm running nginx on the server and I go to the IP in my browser. For whatever reason, I'm just getting timed out right now.

edit: im expecting a Bad Gateway, im getting nothing

Thanks in advance,

I haven't done anything with the default config file...
My `etc/nginx/sites-available/default` looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-52-36-167-131.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/test.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

`sudo service nginx status` looks like this

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-06-19 02:06:09 UTC; 8s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 9149 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9161 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9152 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9162 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─9162 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─9163 nginx: worker process

Jun 19 02:06:09 ip-172-31-25-6 systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jun 19 02:06:09 ip-172-31-25-6 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jun 19 02:06:09 ip-172-31-25-6 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Jun 19 02:06:09 ip-172-31-25-6 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

When I `curl -I ec2-52-36-167-131.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` on the server I get the bad gateway I'm expecting, but on my local machine I get a timeout.

Comment: Are you going to the ip address directly or relying on dns resolution? Also please consider restarting the server so the ip address/name of the server is changed. Do you need the slash at the end of the proxy_pass ? [doco](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) does not require it.

Comment: ive tried with the slash at the end of the proxy_pass both there or not, seems to not matter.

Comment: I'm going to the IP, havent configured the DNS yet. I restarted the server, thinking about shutting it down and starting a new instance

Comment: common reasons [including is php running](https://bobcares.com/blog/502-bad-gateway-nginx/)?

Comment: I terminated the server, trying again with a new instance, still not getting connected. to be clear, i am NOT getting a bad gateway error, im not getting anything.

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` is successful. big shrug. still can't access it

Answer (score 1):

Solved, it was a problem in the AWS security groups.

found it here: [nginx website on Ubuntu 18 not loading on public IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283663/nginx-website-on-ubuntu-18-not-loading-on-public-ip)

Answer (score 0):

Jesus...
After few hours of debugging I found out that without HTTPS set up on fresh nginx I had to add `http://` in front of EC2 instance DNS ...